# File organization and manipulation in DB Systems

Tags: c, database, indexing, record

What are the C functions that allow to load blocks of records into RAM buffers, read/write records from/to blocks, and write blocks to disk?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of fundamental system calls:

- [read](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html)
- [write](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html)
- [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

The rest, if anything, is most likely to be built on top of it.